# Android SystemUI glitches in Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

This bug **only** occurs on my Nexus 5 and my Nexus 7 running **Lollipop**.

**EDIT**

This bug also occurs in the new **Inbox** app by **Google**, when I'm going into *Inbox > Settings > Notifications > any item and go back*...

**/EDIT**

- compileSdkVersion 21
- buildToolsVersion 21.1.1
- compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'

I'm having a `GalleryActivity` that shows multiple images, once per page (inside a `ViewPager`. When I hit the back button, sometimes the Android's SystemUI have glitches.

**Normal view**

[image: normal]

**Glitched view**

[image: glitched]

See how the views repeats themselves, and inside the system itself?

A simple touch event brings back the normal SystemUI views.

**What is going on?**

Might be similar to:

- [Android 5 screen glitch/static with Google Maps Fragment inside a Viewpager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139494/)
- [Android Lollipop Activity Screen corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27224394/)

Comment: Just for reference sake, this is the issue in Google's Android issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81832&q=systemui%20transparent&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Setting `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` is a kind of extreme solution, as graphical performance is likely to be very bad.

If you can pinpoint the view that is misbehaving and causing this issue, a better fix would be to switch it to software rendering instead, via [`setLayerType()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayerType%28int,%20android.graphics.Paint%29), e.g.

```
view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Funny thing is, I haven't experienced any rendering glitches with Lollipop so far, but we did see them in KITKAT (as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24272044/flipanimation-causing-issue-in-4-4-3)), and only when **WebViews** are present on the screen.

I would recommend experimenting with toggling this on different views until the problem is isolated (especially if it's easy to reproduce).

---

So far, every occurence of this issue has been related to WebViews (or components that use WebView, such as AdMob). According to [the AOSP Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=70914) the problem is fixed in Android 5.0, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @shkschneider Yes, I'd hope too. But seeing as this was broken a while ago and there has been no feedback, I wouldn't hold my breath. We've been going with this ugly workaround for a while now. :(

Comment: Its the problem with the way Android L handles web view data rendering. webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); solves the problem.

Comment: Ran into this problem as well with a WebView shown within a ViewPager. It was 100% repeatable by paging between WebViews and then navigating away from the activity. Strangely the display corruption never occurs on the WebView itself -- it happens on a completely separate activity: it would show up when returning to the launcher activity, two steps back in the navigation list. I haven't been able to replicate the issue since turning off hardware acceleration for the WebView using setLayerType.

Comment: @matiash-Hi, I tried both but not working for me. My layout is going below "statusbar" and "navigationbar". whn I update my Textview dynamically thn screen automatically got right but I need to keep screen proper before dynamic updation also...

Answer (score 2):

I've seen UI glitches with Lollipop, though different than yours.  The only *workaround* I found was disabling hardware acceleration:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

at the Activity or Application level.  If this resolves your glitches, make sure to report this to Google as this would indicate a bug in the platform.  There is already at least one open report with them already.

I certainly wouldn't want to deploy an application with this setting, it's really only intended to answer the WHY and help prove that it's not a bug in your code.

Hope this helps!

EDIT 12/10/2014:

@matiash offered a much more precise answer than this "sledgehammer" suggestion.  I was seeing drawing glitches mostly on the ActionBar in a multi-tab app with ViewPager, and always on tabs/pages without any WebView at all.  However, one of my tabs/fragments does have an embedded WebView, and when setting it to software rendering, my glitches appear to have gone away. I'm not at all uncomfortable putting the workaround suggested by @matiash in a shipping app...though it still points to some underlying issue in the platform.

Comment: So you're thinking, like me, that this is a platform/framework bug?

Comment: I have reproducible glitches very similar to the "Google Maps Fragment inside a ViewPager" link you've shown.  Disabling hardware acceleration fixed it.  I've reported to Google, still awaiting feedback.  Not sure if your problem is the same, but its easy enough to try...

Comment: Disabling hardware acceleration (as extreme as this is for a "fix") seems to prevent that issue but also makes every lollipop animations (like ripples) very slow and so a bit ugly...

Comment: Hope to see a fix from Google soon! Glad to have helped

Comment: I know this does solve my issue by decreasing my application efficiency, but it's the only working thing I found out there. Hope to see a fix from Google too. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have also witnessed this problem in my own app.

[Any Android devs ever experience this kind of visual static? (see picture)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27488360/any-android-devs-ever-experience-this-kind-of-visual-static-see-picture)

Not only did I get that kind of visual static, but also repeated drawing.  Only witnessed it on Nexus 5 with 5.0 when developing with api 21 and support library 21.0.+.

For me its not very reproducible.  It will happen repeatedly during one session of use, but the next day I won't be able to reproduce it.

I am not using any WebViews (accept maybe via admob).  I am using ViewPagers with fragments.  I am also using DragSortList and first started seeing the issue in Activities that used it.

https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview

How reproducible is it for you guys?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to set `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in your `Fragment` layout? this will make sure the layout is below the `statusBar`, im not really sure about the navigation buttons but i guess this should work for it too.

Comment: that's freaking weird. how it happens exactly ? is there any scenario that it happens on it?

Comment: It happens most of the times when I'm viewing a large image. But as said in my question, I reproduced the same error (SystemUI getting transparent) on the new Inbox app by Google...

Answer (score 0):

Call request layout on `DecorView` after rendering:

```
getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().requestLayout();
```

I call it using `postDelay()` in `WebViewClient.onPageFinished()`. It's not a perfect solution (just a workaround) but maybe better way like LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE.

Answer (score -1):

.........go to settings and then developer options(if they are not visible... go to about phone then click on build number 7-10 times and developer mode will be on)  and there scroll down and untick 'show layout bounds' and you are done. its simple and easy.

Comment: The question's referring to the graphics getting displayed in the system UI areas (system buttons and system bar), not the layout bounds.