# Android Lollipop Activity Screen corrupted

Tags: android, android-activity, android-5.0-lollipop

I build my App with Android Lollipop SDK (21). After opening some activities and close they, one activity has this corrupted screen. It looks like a Memory error, but this happens only on Android Lollipop devices. In the Logcat i cant see errors.

Any ideas what this is?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a `WebView` (or `AdView`) widget in your app, by chance? Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27172217/android-systemui-glitches ?

Comment: webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); solves the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you this worked for my app which uses WebView. I was experiencing the exact same corruption as pointed out by @Zenco.

(I am using a Nexus 5 running Lollipop 5.0.1)

Setting LayerType to TYPE SOFTWARE worked for me. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It should also happen on 4.4. Try to always assign a background to your fragment or activity.
**update**
Somebody did try using a transparent bkg and it didn't work.

Comment: Do you know why this happens?

Comment: No idea i guess it is caused by some kind of graphic problem in the sdk. did you try it? @Zenco?

Comment: Yes, but i cant reproduce this. I vote your answer up, if this effect doesnt appear.

Comment: This solution did work with me.

Comment: Have you set the activity background in the styles.xml for all activities?
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/my_background</item>

Comment: No usually i set it into the xml layout because in my case every activity has a different background

Comment: Damn, your solution doesnt work for me.

Comment: @Zenco are you sure? if you have a fragment inside your activity it is important to set his background

Comment: Yes, i understand. I have a FragmentActivity with a ViewPager. But the corrupt Activity had already a background color `android:background="#000"`. I set a global background in the styles.xml.

Comment: And each fragment included the viewpager and the fragments into it have a background set? Try to set the activity background into the layout xml.

Comment: @Zenco So did it work for you? Seems to be not working for me...

Comment: Sorry, i had been no time to test it.

Comment: It happens because of `hardware acceleration. webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); solves the problem.

Comment: changing to software rendering is *not* a solution.

Comment: Worked for me,Try this too : http://stackoverflow.com/a/28132032/4693438

Answer (score 1):

The solution

```
webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

is OK, but a bit overkill since this issue only applies to Nexus devices on 5.0 Lollipop. Why punish all phone models?

```
boolean isLollipop = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP;
boolean isNexus = android.os.Build.MODEL.toLowerCase().contains("nexus");

if (isLollipop && isNexus) {
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```

This code assumes that Google will fix the problem in the next version of the OS.

**Edit**

As of 5.1 this has been fixed, which this code handles.