# Android Views Looks Distorted / Scrambled in Android 5 Lollipop

Tags: android, view, static, android-5.0-lollipop, distortion

This seems to only happen on my Nexus 5 with Android 5.0 Lollipop installed.

After navigating through 5-6 activities, I start to see distortion in the view rendering, here's a part of the screen distorted below.

Is anyone facing anything similar? And any idea on how to remedy this?

[image]

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27224394/android-lollipop-activity-screen-corrupted/27224514#27224514

Comment: From what I understand the solution is to assign a background to a root view in XML? I use layouts w/ background assigned in the root view already but this is still happening. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: I don't know if is the same problem but i had a similar problem and the solution to fix it was give a background to each layout.

Comment: by layout do you mean root view of each activity layout? Or every partial layout as well ? Also did you use a transparent image or a transparent color resource ?

Comment: Yes sure i mean the root view o each layout, try using a @color doesn't matter which one it could also be trasparent

Comment: I have tried to add a background to every root element but this does not seem to resolve this for me.

Comment: In my case I found that transparent background did not resolve this across all SDKs. Lower SDKs do not support transparent color. To resolve I used a solid color for activity background that worked well with the UI design/colors.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I found that adding a transparent background to all root views did not resolve this across all SDKs. Lower SDKs do not support transparent color.

To resolve I used a solid color for activity background that worked well with the UI design/colors.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the ART (Android run time) issue. As Google introduced ART by replacing the DVM for android 5 devices (lollipop devices).

ART makes less frequent calls to garbage collector due to which it makes memory leak situation and due to which it makes UI hangs/distorted.

[UI distortion issue on Android 5.0 Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617847/ui-distortion-issue-on-android-5-0-lollipop)