# UI distortion issue on Android 5.0 Lollipop

Tags: android, rendering, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

On LG Nexus 4 (android 5.0.1) we are facing a strange issue, UI got distorted after exploring the app for some time.

Screen shot is at below link.

[image]

Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: It may be rendering issue. Is this issue occurring only on Nexus 4?

Comment: This issue is occurring only on lollipop. We have only LG Nexus with Lollipop update.

Comment: Not able to reproduce, as we get missing shared libraries issue on emulator.

Comment: Got the same issue, still looking for a way to resolve

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem recently. These solutions helped me:
[Android SystemUI glitches in Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27172217/android-systemui-glitches)
 and [Android Lollipop Activity Screen corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27224394/android-lollipop-activity-screen-corrupted/27224514#27224514)

For me the problem were some WebViews that were distorting my layouts.