# android lollipop animation glitch

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-animation, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a strange behaviour with the default layout animation in devices running Android 5 (Lollipop). I am using an activity with multiple Fragments which are replaced at runtime using the default fragment manager. When replacing the old fragment, i want to use an animation for a smooth ui flow. On pre-lollipop devices the animation works like expected, but on devices running the latest os, the animation between fragment glitches:

[image: Glitch screen shot]

I tried using the default animation xml tag

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

Because it does not work, i changed it using this code with no effect

```
mTransaction = mManager.beginTransaction();
        mTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);
        mTransaction.remove(mFragment);
        mTransaction.add(R.id.container, mFragment, "fragment");
        mTransaction.commit();
```

I have tested the code on different devices and in the android emulator. The strange thing is, that it works like expected on devices running pre-lollipop **and in** the android emulator running the latest OS (5.0.1). 
But it does not work on devices like Nexus 4 and Nexus 5 running Android 5.0

Any suggestions? Any Help?

Thanks in Advance

**EDIT:**

It seems to be a bug depending on the used device. I have tested the code on different devices (Samsung Galaxy S4, HTC (One mini2, One M8, Desire S), Nexus 4&5), and it only appears on google nexus devices.

**EDIT**

One Workaround to fix the animation issue is to disable the hardware acceleration via the

`<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false">`

tag in the app Manifest. But using this makes the app very slow.

**Solution**

The solution to fix this issue is to set a background image/color/drawable to the activity. [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27963767/graphical-bug-while-changing-fragment-with-api-21?lq=1)

Comment: I am experiencing the same type of problem with a Nexus 5: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27993851/actionbar-graphic-disrupted-after-viewpager-activity)

Comment: See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27224514/1939607

Comment: Did you declare the use of opengl in your android manifest? I had similar issues with android < 5.0 in the past and getting rid of the opengl declaration solved the problem

Comment: No, I don't use OpenGl in this app and so there is no OpenGl tag declared in the manifest

Comment: since you find the solution on your own consider responding your own question here

Comment: Just add in root layout android:layerType="software"

Answer (score 2):

Set the `background` color of the root activity (also when not visible to the user!) and the graphical glitch is gone.

Comment: This solution is only working for a few devices. Still have this issue on Nexus 5

Comment: I had the same problem of glitch but playing a youtube video with its Youtube Api Library. The issue was only in Nexus 5 when I changed the orientation. I solved it setting the background color of the root layout everytime there is a orientation change.