# Graphical bug while changing fragment with API 21

Tags: android, fragment

I have a graphical problem with my nexus 5.
While I changing fragment, before new fragment appears, there is this big square with a portion of the new fragment.
The transition isn't smooth.

[image: picture]

I use getSupportFragmentManager() for fragment.
With the emulator(API 21) and other devices(API < 21) is all ok, with my device(API 21) i have this problem.
Some ideas?

EDIT: This error occurs only when (and every time) a fragment is replace, not when it is added.

Comment: I noticed similar glitch also with Chrome and other apps while opening new Activities on devices running API 21. That's to say, if even Chrome suffers from this problem, I suppose that is something which is going to get fixed by system updates. Anyone noticed similar problems? If yes in which app?

Comment: Thanks bonnyz...The problem is that in my application this error occur every time i replace a fragment and it is very annoying

Comment: Why not just take a screenshot so it is more clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED!!!

I've found the solution.
I've set the background color of root activity(also if it is never shown like in my case) and the graphical glitch is gone.

Comment: This is the most simplest fix to the most weirdest issue.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in the android graphics lib on all nexus devices. I have a similar issue using the FragmentManger, [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27897850/android-lollipop-animation-glitch)

To fix this issue on nexus devices, add the

`<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false">`

tag, but this will make the app very slow.

**EDIT:**

There are several Threads in the Google issue tracker or at stackoverflow describing this problem

[Issue 82631](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82631&q=animation&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27224394/android-lollipop-activity-screen-corrupted)

Comment: More correct way to set hardwareAccelerated="false" for an Activity, but not an Application. But still it seems for me as a workaround

Comment: This will only help if his minSDK is less than 14: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#hwaccel.