# Exiting fullscreen activity sometimes leaves artifacts in action bar and system navigation areas

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-fullscreen, visual-artifacts

I have a normal Activity (A) with visible Action Bar which launches another **fullscreen** activity (B) to display photos. When (B) finishes and activity (A) is displayed back **sometimes** I can see the following picture:

[image: Action bar and navigation area artifacts]

Please note visual distortion of action bar and navigation areas.
The above artifacts disappear only when I start interacting with the activity, scrolling it, etc.

Full screen activity code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActionBar supportActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    supportActionBar.hide();
}
```

1. No hints in AndroidManifest.xml are used.
2. Support libraries are used (appcompat)
3. Reproduced on Nexus 4, Android 5.0.1

The only style customization that I have:

```
 <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat" tools:ignore="NewApi">
    <!-- Text appearance -->
    <item name="android:textColorLink">@color/linkColor</item>
</style>
```

Does anybody know any clues why is that ?

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug on Lollipop Nexus devices.  As workaround it would be possible to disable hardware acceleration on manifest activity's declaration:
`android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` (this slows graphic performances).

Comment: Do you have any reference links to this issue ?

Comment: my question http://stackoverflow.com/q/27993851/4274296
and this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/27897850/4274296

Comment: I had the opposite issue actually. I disabled hardwareAcceleration, and then these issues started. Reading this post I remembered this again, re-enabled hardwareAcceleration and BAM, problems all gone!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same thing with my application. However, the folowing thing seem to fix that up (at list for me):

```
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    findViewById(R.id.root).setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            findViewById(R.id.root).setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

As you can see - I'm trying to switch off Hardware acceleration and than switch it on again for my main root view in the layout. I don't actully know why changing view type worked because that's what you can find on [HA Thread](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html):

> Note: You currently cannot enable hardware acceleration at the view level. View layers have other functions besides disabling hardware acceleration. See View layers for more information about their uses.