# Why is my ActionBar/Toolbar transparent and showing stuff that is in the list?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-6.0-marshmallow

This is kind of bizarre and doesn't happen on all phones, but seemingly randomly started happening to me. See the below screenshot. The ToolBar is fine when I first open this activity, but then when I click on the photo (which opens in a new activity) and go back, I get the following:

[image: Screenshot]

Any ideas on what could cause this? I am on Marshmallow on Nexus 5 (Haven't been able to reproduce on other phones).

Comment: gotta show some code.

Comment: Model of phone? It is rooted? Custom firmware?

Comment: Nexus 5. 6.0, no root, stock

Comment: There were issues about some corruption of ActionBar on Nexus 5, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27897850/4274296) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29509846/4274296)