# Any Android devs ever experience this kind of visual static? (see picture)

Tags: android

It seems to have started happening after my nexus 5 got its 5.0 update and after I started using the new AppCompat v7 21.0.0 support library.

I can't reproduce the probably reliably, and sometimes the problem presents itself as a redrawing of a segment of the UI again and again, and sometimes is comprised of black and white patterns (not colored static as you seehere).  So for example, sometimes a block of the UI that stretches from the left to the right of the screen and goes 20% down the screen, will be repeatedly drawn (with or without static) 5 times down the screen sequentially (so it will be at 0%, 20%, 40%... etc).

Just seems to be happening this terribly in my app, but I have seen small hints of it in other apps.

Anybody ever have this bizarre problem?

Thanks in advance!

[image: visual static]

Comment: I had the same problem on some complex views.  The views in questions where usualy containing webviews, and it only happened on my Nexus 5.   

This seemed to work as a solution for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27172217/android-systemui-glitches

Comment: @BrentWatson, Thanks.  Strangely enough, this view nor many other views that had these bizarre issues were using WebViews.  However, views that were being dismissed as this view was being created may have included WebViews.  I went ahead and made sure all my WebViews were good to go as per: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27172217/android-systemui-glitches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27172217/android-systemui-glitches).  It may have helped.  I haven't seen the problem occur again but when it did it did so inconsistently so its hard to tell.  Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: I had this occur on one of my apps and I think it was ultimately some weird bug in my code.  I'm digging through to see if I can find the root cause.

Comment: @bryan, I wouldn't even know where to start looking for a bug in my code that would cause something like this.  Short of writing my own pixel pushing code, I can't think of something I could do in the android framework that would result in the framework drawing random colors on the screen.

Comment: What's your target API level and the level of app compat you're using?

Comment: @bryan, target API is 21 and AppCompat is v7 21.0.0 as per  
  
`compile com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0`
  
But like I said, I'm not experiencing the issue anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Well,

After making this post, I continued to search Stack Overflow for possible solutions and finally stumbled upon the right search key words that landed me on various questions that were very similar but not quite the same as mine.  I ultimately followed the WebView advice as suggested on this post: [Android SystemUI glitches in Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27172217/android-systemui-glitches).  I haven't seen the problem happen again on my Nexus 5, but I can't be sure the WebView related solution fixed it because the problem was extremely intermittent and my Nexus 5 has since been updated to 5.0.1.  Anyway, worth trying the WebView solution if you are dealing with this issue.